# MySQL TIMEDIFF() returns the differences between two times and Sum of time

Tags: mysql

my query is i want find the sum with the timediff function any help

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF( timefrom, timeto )
FROM `leaveapply`
WHERE userid = '21'
GROUP BY leavetype
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

The following statement will return the time like this

```
00:00:00
00:00:00
01:00:00
02:00:00
```

i want to sum and get the result , 
like this `03:00:00`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select sum(
            SELECT TIMEDIFF( timefrom, timeto ) FROM `leaveapply`
            WHERE userid = '21'
            GROUP BY leavetype
          ) as total
```